# order of the outputs for the MATLAB solve function

Tags: matlab

I have been tinkering with the MATLAB solve function for a while, but cannot seem how it determines the order that it outputs the symbolic variables.

Specifically, I have a system of equations that I want to solve simultaneously.

```
a = f(a, b, c, d)
b = f(a, b, c, d)
c = f(a, b, c, d)
d = f(a, b, c, d)
```

and these equations are symbolic and have other symbolic variables (aside from a, b, c, and d). (so the solution outputs aren't numeric, but are symbolic).

For example, when I am solving the for the equations of motion for an inverted spring pendulum, I have two equations that are both dependent on phiDDot and lenDDot. I use the solve function to solve for phiDDot and lenDDot separately using this call:

```
[eom2, eom1] = solve(Lag(1)==0, Lag(2)==0, ddphi, ddlen);
```

The solution for ddphi corresponds to the second term of the matrix outputted, while ddlen corresponds to the first term of the matrix. I was wondering whether there was some way to tell MATLAB to output ddphi first and ddlen second, or at least determine what order they are outputted. Not knowing the order of the variables becomes a big problem when I am solving for more than 4 variables, and trying to solve the differential equations using ode45.

Any advice would be helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it's alphabetical based on the ASCII values of the variable names in your equations. As per the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#btrwaee-1) for `solve`, [`sym/symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symvar.html) is used to parse the equations in the case where you don't supply the names of output variables. The help for `sym/symvar` indicates that it returns variables in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), i.e. alphabetical ([`symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) does the same, even though it doesn't say so, by making calls to [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)). If you look at the actual code for solve.m (type `edit solve` in your command window) and examine the sub-function called `assignOutputs` (line 190 in R2012b) you'll see that it makes a call to [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) and that there's a comment about lexicographical order.

In R2012b (and likely earlier) the documentation differs from that of R2013a in a way that seems relevant to your issue. In R2013a, [this sentence is added](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#outputarg_y1yN):

> If you explicitly specify independent variables `vars`, then the solver uses the same order
>   to return the solutions.

I'm still running R2012b, so I can't confirm this different behavior.