# Control the order of output for symbolic expressions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Can I control the order of output for MATLAB symbolic expressions?

For example:

```
syms x y  
f=y*x
```

MATLAB will normally return:

```
f=  
x*y
```

but I'd like to get:

```
f=  
y*x
```

I'm using MATLAB R2012b. How can I do this?

NEW EDIT 2016/11/9
I found these yesterday and it seems so weird to me:
Under R2008a

```
%%feedback.m
function H=feedback(G1,G2,key)  
if nargin==2
    key=-1;
end
H=G1/(sym(1)-key*G1*G2);
H=simple(H);

%%matlab command window
syms G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 H1 H2 H3 H4
c1=feedback(G4*G5,H3);
c2=feedback(G2*G3,H2);
c3=feedback(c1*c2,H4/G2/G5);
G=feedback(c3*G1*G6,H1);
pretty(G)
```

MATLAB returns

```
G=
G3 G2 G4 G5 G1 G6/(1 + G2 G3 H2 + G4 G5 H3 + G4 G5 H3 G2 G3 H2 + G4 G3 H4 + G3 G2 G4 G5 G1 G6 H1)
```

Unfortunately, my R2008a doesn't have the symbolic math toolbox (I've been trying reinstallment many times, doesn't work). Hence I can't verify if it's true. I think if 2008a can make it, why can't 2012b.
I hope this may be helpful to my problem asked above.

Comment: Not that it's the issue, but why are you using a 4,5 year old MATLAB version? That'll give rise to lots of deprecated functions and compatibility issues with newer versions.

Comment: @Adriaan: sadly, that is true: it's a reality of the tool that's driving me away from it to be honest -- MATLAB isn't made with long-term support in mind. Like, at all: every new version seems to come with things that break at least some old code. Sometimes, pretty badly. Most other languages at least provide some sort guarantee of backwards compatibility across versions. That is part of the reason why I still work with MATLAB R2010a much of my time, because my company *did* start projects requiring long-term support, and those projects will not be done with R2010a for at least 2 more years.

Comment: If you just want to reverse the sortorder, see the answer that I found. If you want to do things that are more complicated, I doubt that there will be an easy way. (As any solution should obviously generalize to work in all possible situations).

Comment: @Adriaan I totally agree with Rody Oldenhuis. Every half year MATLAB has another new version. And most annoying, there're always big changes in the new version. Sometimes it even change the funtions that I used to use. It just drives me crazy....

Comment: @Sam.X. How is the order of the variables 'controlled' in the example? It appears pretty random to me, first there is G2 G3 and at another spot there is G3 G2

Comment: @Dennis In the example above, it means every two symbols CANNOT commute their positions (say, G2*G3~=G3*G2). After computing c1 to c3 by  hand you'd find out they're not random but strict to the feedback formula.

Comment: Look, it's really not clear what you're asking here...the symbolic toolbox of course knows that `AB ≠ BA` if `A` and `B` are matrices. Problem is, if you don't tell the toolbox that they are matrices, then it will assume they are scalars, in which case `AB = BA` and then you will have lost "control" over the order. So I *suspect* @DennisJaheruddin is right and you're just using the toolbox wrong, but it's kinda hard for us to follow you. Can you give a **clear** and **concise** example of (1) what you want to do accomplish, (2) what you've tried, and (3) what's not good about that?

Comment: Perhaps this is best done by deleting this question and just asking a new one, this one's getting cluttered and not very useful to any future visitors with similar problems...

Comment: @Rody OK, but I just can't delete (it says this has been answered). I'll ask another question. Thanks for your enthusiasm and patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this applies to R2012b, but on my R2010a, the class `sym` has a `disp` method, which is run when displaying your little function (and of course, all `sym` objects). Here is the relevant code:

```
allstrs = mupadmex(X.s,0);
allstrs = strrep(allstrs,'MLVar','');
disp(allstrs);
```

where `X` is the `sym` object, and `s` is a `private` property thereof.

The function `mupadmex()` is, as the name implies, a MEX binary. The corresponding M-code contains this:

```
%   MUPADMEX(STMT) executes STMT in MuPAD. STMT must be a string or cell
%   array of strings. A cell array is converted into a MuPAD matrix or array.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(STMT) executes STMT in MuPAD and returns the result as
%   sym object Y. STMT must be a string or cell array of strings. If STMT
%   is a cell Y is a string reference instead of a sym.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(FCN,ARG1,ARG2, ...) evaluates FCN(ARG1,ARG2,...). The inputs
%   must be strings.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(... ,0) returns Y as a string instead of a sym.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(REF ,1) adds REF to the garbage list.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(STMT,2) frees any garbage.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,3) formats VAL as 'symr'.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,4) formats VAL as 'symfl'.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,5) toggles the trace feature. VAL must be 'on' or 'off'.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(STMT,6) resets MuPAD.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,7) toggles the pretty-print feature.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,8) sets the complex unit. VAL is 'I' or 'sqrtmone'.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(... ,9) returns Y as a logical instead of a sym.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,10) toggles the synchronous evaluation mode (out-of-process kernel only).
%   Y = MUPADMEX(... ,11) returns Y as a string reference.
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,12) print out memory usage
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,13) toggles lazy evaluation mode
%   Y = MUPADMEX(VAL ,14) evaluates all the lazy statements
%   [Y,STATUS] = ... sets STATUS to 0 if the command completes without error
%   and otherwise sets STATUS to 1 and Y to the error string.
```

As you can see, it says nothing about *formatting* the string.

So, in short, you can do the following:

1. You'd have to alter the toolbox code
2. Write a display wrapper like this:

   ```
   function disp_sym(X)

       str = evalc('X');
       str = regexp(str, '=', 'split');
       fml = strtrim(str{2});
       eq  = str{1};

       fml = regexp(fml, '*', 'split');
       fml = fml(end:-1:1);

       disp( [eq '=' sprintf('%s*', fml{1:end-1}) fml{end}]);

   end
   ```

   But, that gets fugly, overly specific and non-portable really quickly.

Comment: I enjoy the creativity, but I assume that this specific display wrapper is just an example that may or may not work for all cases. (The last line already implies this but an explicit warning would seem like a good idea). -- Did not try to test it, but I could imagine some strange things happening when you have complicated expressions like a times b to the power c times d

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin indeed, this one is specific to the OP's use-case, which may or may not suffice. Anyway, I strongly advise against this route, but in some cases bad advice is the only possible advice.

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis: I think changing the toolbox code may be risky, so I prefer the second solution. But there's still a problem: after using your disp_sym function, I found this function just display the expression reversely, but the there's no variable saved in MATLAB. All I want is: after using a (self-defined) function, MATLAB can save a sym variable, whose value is y*x for example. Is that possible??

Comment: @Sam.X. ...but `y*x == x*y`? What do you want to change then, other than how it's displayed?

Comment: @Rody Oldenhuis: actually I want to use just one symbol to denote a matrix (say, A is a matrix, B is the other matrix). In this case, A*B~=B*A. Hence I other than how it displays, I pay more attention to how I can let MATLAB save my sym-expressions...

Comment: @Sam.X. That is quite a different question then 'controlling the order of the output' as it would also mean that A*B+B*A should not be simplified. As it is a different question, I would recommend you to think carefully what you want and describe it clearly in a new question. If you think the question as written here is answered, consider accepting any of the answers (or if you think the question as written here is meaningless for future visitors, consider deleting it). -- Also note that you are able to define sybolic matrices in case that is what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @Dennis Don't know if I'm right. In order to achieve my goal, the first thing is to control the order. Once I can control every item, the simplification can be easily done. So the problem I asked above is the first step. But it seems a really difficult problem and I still cannot figure it out. But anyway, thanks for your enthusiasm and patience.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found [an answer by @horchler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17264799/983722) which appears to answer this question fully. Even though it was given as an answer to a different question.

Note that I quote the answer, but that I will not put it in a quote block to enhance readability:

---

I believe that it's alphabetical based on the ASCII values of the variable names in your equations. As per the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#btrwaee-1) for `solve`, [`sym/symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symvar.html) is used to parse the equations in the case where you don't supply the names of output variables. The help for `sym/symvar` indicates that it returns variables in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), i.e. alphabetical ([`symvar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) does the same, even though it doesn't say so, by making calls to [`setdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)). If you look at the actual code for solve.m (type `edit solve` in your command window) and examine the sub-function called `assignOutputs` (line 190 in R2012b) you'll see that it makes a call to [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) and that there's a comment about lexicographical order.

In R2012b (and likely earlier) the documentation differs from that of R2013a in a way that seems relevant to your issue. In R2013a, [this sentence is added](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html#outputarg_y1yN):

> If you explicitly specify independent variables `vars`, then the solver uses the same order
>   to return the solutions.

I'm still running R2012b, so I can't confirm this different behavior.

Comment: I've read this before asking. I know it may be related my question, but I still can't figure it out. For one thing, I didn't use the solve function. I did see the sub-function mentioned above, but I still don't know how to alter the code. For another, even though I know how to rewrite it, I don't know in which m file I should put the new codes. Also, changing the toolbox code may be risky.....

Comment: @Sam.X. I would start the exploration in sym/symvar. If the code is accesible, you should be able to flip a sort somewhere. Otherwise you may be out of luck. -- You are of course right that changing basic matlab code could lead to unexpected results, so play at your own risk. -- Just a thought, but does it help if you use `syms y x'? OR if you use `syms Bx Ay` in the last case it should be comparatively easy to post process the output by replacing Ay with y and Bx with x.

Comment: For the second solution, I just can't define x', the error says: Not a valid variable name. As for the Bx and Ay, well, it 'll always return f=Ay*Bx.....orz....And I'm now exploration in sym/symvar, and I found there're many functions I've never seen.....ToT....

Comment: @Sam.X. The quote was not supposed to be there, i meant `syms y x` instead of `syms x y`. -- However, if you say that defining `Bx` and `Ay` will always return `f=Ay*Bx` then it sounds like success. Just replace `Ay` by `y` and `Bx` by `x` in the output and you have your desired `f=y*x`

Comment: Well, after using subs function to replace Ay by y and Bx by x (`f=subs(f,[Ay,Bx],[y,x])` ), MATLAB still change the order of output automatically by returning:`f=x*y`

Comment: Of course the output is treated as symbols when you use a symbolic function to do the substitution. Instead store the output as a string and use string functions to do the substitution.

Comment: I know string variables can meet my demands. But I was thinking if the symbolic variables can do this. And I've seen a video which showed R2008a could do that (but I couldn't verify it since my 2008a didn't have the symbolic math toolbox). To my surprised, R2012b can't do that....